# C# MVC utilising parameter on default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using MVC 4.

My default route on my site is `Home/Index` so when the user enters the URL `www.example.com` it goes to that route.

Could you let me know if it is also possible to receive a parameter appended to that URL i.e. `www.example.com/param`? It works if I use `www.example.com/Home/Index/param` but that's not ideal.

I'm guessing its something I need to add to the `Global.asax` but I can't find examples anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Home_all",
            "/{*actions}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
```

But be aware that route will match all urls , so you need to register it at last :) That Routing will be called like this in  your Home Controller for example... Actions will be a part from the url, and you can even add some parameter in the query string

```
    public ActionResult Index(string actions, string id)
    {
    }
```